# How to get element value using angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to get the attribute value of element but return undefined.

html

```
<button id="myId" ng-click="hi($event)">click me</button>
```

js

```
$scope.hi = function (e) {
   var elem = angular.element(e.srcElement);
   alert(elem.attr("id"));

}
```

why i get undefined?

Answer (score 1):

Change `e.srcElement` to `e.target`

example:

```
 $scope.hi = function (e) {

    var elem = angular.element(e.target);
      alert(elem.attr("id"));
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/td8pb/)

OR u can use

```
$scope.hi = function (e) {
     alert(e.target.id);
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/V5QXc/)**

Answer (score 0):

`$event` will pass the click event to your function.

For working with the element itself, you should use a [**directive**](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

```
 app.directive('mydirectiver', function() {
return {

    link: function(scope,element,attrs){

        //element will point to the element

        //attrs will point to the elements attributes

    }

};
});
```

I strongly recommend the lecture of the Angular docs on directives. They are a little confusing in the beginning, but you should be able to wrap your head around the concept very fast and benefit from their power.